# Error: assessment nested too deep ; infinite recursion

Tags: r

When running the following application I encounter the following error which impedes to finalize the following function. Would you kindly suggest a way to finalize this function as to obtain the appropriate response

```
z  <- list(c(c(1,2,3,4,5,5,6,5,4,2,5,2,5,3,6,3,6,3,5,5,2,2,4),c(2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4,2,5,2,4,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,3,3)),c(c(1,2,3,4,5,5,6,5,4,2,5,2,5,3,6,3,6,3,5,5,2,2,4),c(2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4,2,5,2,4,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,3,3)))

g   <- seq(1:length(z))
fun <- function (x) seq(1:length(z[[x]]))
d   <- lapply(g,fun)

Dii   <-  function(i)      {
o   <-   d[[i]] 
mapply ( function (x, y) Box.test( z[[x]][[y]] , lag = length ( z[[x]]
[[y]] ) - 1, type = c("Ljung-Box") , fitdf = 0 )
, g[[i]] , d[[i]]      )
                                      }
Dii  <-  function (x) lapply ( g, Dii )    [[x]][3,]
Da   <- lapply (g, Dii)
# Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
fun  <- function (x) which(Da[[x]] > 0.05)
Daa  <- lapply( g,fun)
# Error in which(Da[[x]] > 0.05) : object 'Da' not found
```

Comment: It is not clear what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: Fyi, this part `length( z[[x]][[y]] ) - 1` is zero for all values of x and y. Maybe you want `lapply(seq_along(z), Dii)`?

Comment: Why the down vote, z is a list with two sublist each with a vector. I want to run the Box.test on each vector and return the resulting Box test

Comment: I downvoted because you ask us how to *obtain the appropriate response* but you don't explain what the appropriate response should be.  In fact you don't explain anything.  It's hard to tell what you are attempting to accomplish here.  I will happily remove my vote if you improve the question.

Comment: Richard you are righ I should have specified the output appologies will do some adding tomorrow.

Comment: Richard must have downvoted and then erased the comment that produced this awnser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that `Dii` calls itself:

```
Dii   <-  function(i)      {
o   <-   d[[i]] 
mapply ( function (x, y) Box.test( z[[x]][[y]] , lag = length ( z[[x]]
[[y]] ) - 1, type = c("Ljung-Box") , fitdf = 0 )
, g[[i]] , d[[i]]      )
                                      }
Dii  <-  function (x) lapply ( g, Dii )    [[x]][3,]
```

You've defined the function twice.  The second definition will be used.

Change the name of one of these:

```
Diii   <-  function(i)      {
o   <-   d[[i]] 
mapply ( function (x, y) Box.test( z[[x]][[y]] , lag = length ( z[[x]]
[[y]] ) - 1, type = c("Ljung-Box") , fitdf = 0 )
, g[[i]] , d[[i]]      )
                                      }
Dii  <-  function (x) lapply ( g, Diii )    [[x]][3,]
```